# Reassigning an Exception to the catch parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, java-7

Consider the following code.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException;

public class ReassignmentICatch {

    public void couldThrowAnException() throws SQLException, IOException {}
    public void rethrow() throws SQLException, IOException {
      try {
         couldThrowAnException();
         System.out.println("Did not throw");
      } catch (Exception e) {   //Line-1
        e = new IOException();  //Line-2    
        throw e;                //Line-3        
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReassignmentICatch rc = new ReassignmentICatch();
        try {
            rc.rethrow();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As i know `catch(Exception e)` in java7 does not catch all exceptions like java6 instead it catches only those exceptions which are mentioned in the declaration of method `couldThrowAnException`. Also Reassigning a new exception to the catch parameter(e) is not allowed that's why we get compilation error at `Line-3`
Is this reassignment not allowed in java6 too. I thought it should be allowed to reassign in java6 so i changed the property of java-compiler in eclipse and set compliance level to 1.6 to see whether this code compiles or not.
The behaviour that i am not able to predict is: 
1.Eclipse is giving same error

> Unhandled exception type Exception

for java 6 7 and 8.
2.When i am trying with command line using `javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 ReassignmentICatch.java` am getting

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with
>   -source 1.6 ReassignmentICatch.java:18: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caugh t or declared to be thrown
>
> ```
>   throw e;
>   ^ 1 error 1 warning
> ```

and with java7 and java8 i am able to compile and run it successfully with output `Did not throw` .Why IDE and command-line are not giving same result.

Can somebody please suggest me what I am missing here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue you are having is caused because of the reasons you stated basically... you cannot throw an exception you didn't state the method can throw.

Now, you did make e an IOException, but the variable itself points to an object of the Exception type. 
instead of those 2 lines

```
e = new IOException();
throw e;
```

why not just doing

```
throw new IOException();
```

it will give you the result you want, and won't give you the error you get now.

Comment: In java7 compiler treats e as a final kind of variable(similar to multicatch feature introduced by java7) thats why is wrong to reassign and throw e again..what i am not getting is why it cannot be compiled in java6 because methods couldThrowAnException and rethrow clearly mention in its declaration that it could throw an IOException. Then whats wrong in reassigning and throwing an exception which is already handled.. Also why i am getting different behaviour when i use command line to compile it?

Comment: cause in Line-1 of your code e is declared as an Exception, not IOException nor SQLException. It's true that you put an IOException in it, but the compiler has no way to predict it.